# BSD conjecture for rank 1 elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, l-functions

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve. The weak Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture predicts that
$$\text{ord}_{s=1}L(E, s)=\text{rank} E(\mathbb{Q}).$$
Thanks to the work of Gross-Zagier and Kolyvagin, we know that this conjecture is true if $\text{ord}_{s=1}L(E, s)\le 1$.

What is known in the case $\text{rank} E(\mathbb{Q})\le 1$? Is it known that if $\text{rank} E(\mathbb{Q})=1$, then $L'(E, 1)\neq 0$?

Thank you!

Comment: In fairness, it's probably worth mentioning that in addition to  the work of G-Z and Kolyvagin,  one also needs the theorem of Wiles et al that every elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ is modular, since [G-Z] and [K] start with the assumption that their elliptic curve is modular.

Comment: ...and a non-vanishing result for special values of L functions.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893669

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following theorem is due to Chris Skinner, in [this 2014 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7294).

> Let E/Q be an elliptic curve such that rank E(Q) = 1 **and** the
>   Tate-Shafarevich group Sha(E / Q) is finite, and some other technical
>   assumptions hold. Then $ord_{s = 1} L(E, s) = 1$, and in particular
>   $L'(E, 1) \ne 0$.

This is, as far as I know, the best one can do at the moment; if you don't know that Sha (or at least its p-primary part for some p) is finite, then you're stuck.